# Python 3D Array Printing Horizontally

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, newline

I am trying to print 3D array of letters horizontally instead of vertically.

I tried iterating through using 3 for loops, but that result prints the letters vertically.

Currently, with the 3 for loops I'm printing this array vertically, but I'd like to have everything side by side for each "board" representation.

My specific array is set up below. This is the result I get when I do print(my_arr) starting with [[], [array((

```py
# As an example of the 3D array that I have
letters = [[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']], [['g', 'h', 'i'], ['j', 'k', 'l']]]

# I'm doing
for l in letters:
    for ll in l:
        for val in ll:
            print(*val, sep='')

Above 3D array is not the exact representation of the array, but I'm getting:

a b c
d e f
g h i
j k l

but, my expected result is:

a b c g h i
d e f j k l

I would like to print this in a format similar to 
a b c g h i
d e f j k l

[[], [array([[' ', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', ' '],
       ['|', ' ', ' ', 'o', 'a', 'a', ' ', '|'],
       ['|', ' ', ' ', 'o', ' ', ' ', ' ', '|'],
       ['|', 'x', 'x', 'o', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
       ['|', 'p', 'p', 'p', ' ', ' ', 'q', '|'],
       ['|', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'q', '|'],
       ['|', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'q', '|'],
       [' ', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', ' ']], dtype='<U1')], [], [array([[' ', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', ' '],
       ['|', ' ', ' ', 'o', ' ', 'a', 'a', '|'],
       ['|', ' ', ' ', 'o', ' ', ' ', ' ', '|'],
       ['|', 'x', 'x', 'o', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
       ['|', ' ', 'p', 'p', 'p', ' ', 'q', '|'],
       ['|', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'q', '|'],
       ['|', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'q', '|'],
       [' ', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', ' ']], dtype='<U1')]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could do for your specific case

```
# As an example of the 3D array that I have
letters = [[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']], [['g', 'h', 'i'], ['j', 'k', 'l']]]


j=0
for i in range(len((letters[j]))):
    for j in range(len(letters)):        
            for k in range(len((letters[j][i]))):  
                print(letters[j][i][k],end = ' ')
    print()
```

Comment: Well, in the first loop, for i in range(len((letters[j]))   the j is not referenced before assignment

Comment: I have changed it now

Comment: Initialising j=0 before the loops does give the result

Comment: Yes, that seems to be working for the example, but not my specific case. But I think I can work with this.

Comment: is there a way to format it in this format with my specific array that I've updated with?

Comment: Provide me with a copyable text version of the array and your expected result.

Comment: I updated my post. (I'm a first time poster so I wasn't sure how to format it)

Comment: And what is the result yo are  expecting. Also how are you reading this to your python code. Can you include these details too to avoid rework

Answer (score 1):

This would do it

```
# As an example of the 3D array that I have
letters = [[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']], [['g', 'h', 'i'], ['j', 'k', 'l']]]

# I'm doing
for l in letters:
    for ll in l:
        for val in ll:
            print(*val,  end = ' ')
    print()
```

**Reason**

Python has a predefined format if you use print(a_variable) then it will go to next line automatically unless you specify explicitly

Comment: Sorry that's not the expected result I wanted

Comment: The order is wrong. I can't think how to do it with these loops, but if you do this it works: `import numpy as np; letters = np.moveaxis(letters, 1, 0)`.